# tamaño texto usando textarea en php

Tags: php

Quiero mostrar comentarios en campo de `PHP` usando `textarea`.
El `script` que tengo es :

```
<td align = "left">
  <textarea  rows="10" cols="60" name= "txtcod">"<?php echo $var34?>"</textarea> </td>
```

El problema es que despues de actualizar la base de datos, no muestra los comentarios completos, solo una parte.
Gracias

Comment: para que la comunidad te pueda apoyar necesitas colocar el código que estas ocupando, el comportamiento esperado y el fallo que se te presenta

Comment: Si tienes acceso a la base de datos, fíjate en la definición de tamaño del campo correspondiente, para descartar que el mismo no tenga espacio suficiente para almacenar todo el texto que tú le pretendes ingresar. Por ejemplo, si el campo está declarado como `VARCHAR(50)`, no puedes insertar un texto que supere los 50 caracteres: en dado caso, la BD trunca el texto e inserta hasta donde cabe.